# Issue with CSS and IE11 with position relative

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer-11

For anyone that can help with CSS on IE-11. I cannot figure out why this code is not working. Only if I comment out the CSS .container_main_box {/*position: relative;*/... does the page load correctly and then the link on the left call the javascript function. I inherited this code and trimmed it down until I can recreate the issue which is what you see here. I have searched and tried everything I could find on the Internet and nothing works. I am really not good with CSS or any front-end stuff so I am really struggling with this. Can anyone help?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>
   <HEAD>
      <TITLE>Temporary</TITLE>
      <SCRIPT type="text/javascript">
          function openMenu() {
               console.log("Called the Javascript function successfully.")  
          }
      </SCRIPT>
      <style>

        .sidebar {
          margin: 0;
          padding: 0px 0px;
          top: -15px;
          width: 180px;
          height: 417px;
          float: left;
          background-color: #2a2e43;
          position: relative;
          overflow: hidden;
          text-align: left;
          overflow-y: hidden;
          border-bottom-color: #f7f6fa;
        }

        .sidebar a {
          display: block;
          text-decoration: none;
          text-align: left;
          font: Regular 11px/13px Helvetica;
          letter-spacing: 0;
          color: #ffffff;
          padding: 8px;
          font-size: 16px;
          overflow-y: hidden;
          border-bottom-color: #f2f2f7;
        }   

        .box_size {
          width: 100%;
        }

        .container {
          padding: 0.2em 0.4em;
          width: 100%;
          height: 100%;
          position: absolute;
          margin-top: 20px;
        }

        .container_main_box {
          position: relative;
          float: left;
          width: 100%;
          height: 75%;
          min-width: 50%;
          max-width: 100%;
          top: -432px;
        }

      </style>

   </HEAD>
   <BODY>
      <DIV class="container">
         <DIV class="sidebar">
            <DIV>
               <A onclick="openMenu()" href="#"><span>First Link</span></A>
            </DIV>
            <DIV>
               <A onclick="openMenu()" href="#"><span>Second Link</span></A>
            </DIV>
         </DIV>
         <DIV class="container_main_box">
            <DIV>
              <DIV class="box_size"><SPAN>Just some content...</SPAN></DIV>
            </DIV>
         </DIV>
      </DIV>
   </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: How about adding what actually *does not work* and also how it *is supposed to work*?

Comment: `.container_main_box` is on top of everything preventing all clicks on `.sidebar`. Not only on IE11 tho. Add different backgroundcolours to your divs and you see the issue.

Comment: JavaScript you are absolutely right! I just added a border dotted and what I did not see before was the div is not aligning up where I expected and sure enough, it is covering the links on the side by laying on top of them. Now to find a solution for this.